# Classify each case in dataframe with significant groups (or clusters) in stratified data

Tags: r, dplyr, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am needing to cluster (perhaps k-means) a dependent variable (Value) considering stratification by two independents (Country; Year); and at the end classify each df case (example top, middle and bottom).

df structure:

```
df <- structure(list(Country = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E"), Year = c(2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L), Value = c(64, 48, 20, 49, 43, 39, 32, 56, 36, 32, 
70, 45, 36, 40, 34, 72, 49, 54, 26, 16)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

What I have done so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(Country, Year, .add = TRUE) %>%
  group_split() %>%
  map_df( ~ .x %>% mutate(cluster =
                            kmeans(.x[, c('Value')], 3)$cluster))
```

However, I am concerned that group stratification is not being incorporated. In my real df the message is returned:

Warning: did not converge in 10 iterations

Comment: Okay, but ... (1) all `Year` values are invariant at 2019; and (2) have you tried anything? StackOverflow isn't a code-for-free service, it is intended to help you with concrete programming problems. The only problem I see here is perhaps that you haven't tried splitting the data into separate datasets by your grouping variables and calling `kmeans` on each one.

Comment: Maybe `clust_list <- by(df, list(df$Year, df$Country), \(x) kmeans(x[, "Value"], 3))`.

Comment: I adjusted the minimum df to have two classes in each categorical variable. I am not sure what I did in the draft code.